# Azure CLI - Powershell

Tags: azure-cli

Opening new Session on Azure CLI always bring to unreachable website

[image: Azure CLI new session window error]

Comment: How about just input https://shell.azure.com?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to open the site in private mode.

[image]

Comment: Nope, it does not work. It looks like a redirection (href) bug